# want the data in the database to go into the react table I made

Tags: reactjs, database

contanier.js

```
...

    getData = () => {
      const originData = this.props.results;
      const data = [
        { id: "test2",  name: "test2", gender: "male", age: 2, birth_date : 2020-09-01 },
        { id: "test3", name: "test3", gender: "other", age:3, birth_date : 2020-09-02 },
      ];
      this.setState({ data, filteredData: data });
    };
```

Code i want

```
getData = () => {
  const originData = this.props.results;
  const data = [ 
                { origindata }
  ];
  this.setState({ data, filteredData: data });
};
```

Currently, the id, name, age, gender, and birth_data are stored in'results'.

I defined'results' as 'origindata'.

I want to put id, name, gender, age, and birth_data from 'origindata' into const data.

But I can't figure out how to put it.

Anyone can tell me? Thank you in advance.

I'll provide more code if you like.

And if the title of the post is strange, let me know what to use as the title.

Comment: Could you show me a originData? how's look like? you can console.log it?

Comment: I uploaded a picture!

Comment: Do you want data format like sample data:
const data = [
        { id: "test2",  name: "test2", gender: "male", age: 2, birth_date : 2020-09-01 },
        { id: "test3", name: "test3", gender: "other", age:3, birth_date : 2020-09-02 },
      ];

Comment: Yes, I want it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with sample.You can custom filed you need like id and name.

```
 const data = originData.map(datum => ({...datum, id: datum.pid, name: datum.pid}));
```